# How to adjust a function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

i am trying to use in C++ the algorithm of Nelder-Mead to minimize a function. I don't understand why this code doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/home/user/CppNumericalSolvers/include/cppoptlib/meta.h"
#include "/home/user/CppNumericalSolvers/include/cppoptlib/problem.h"
#include "/home/user/CppNumericalSolvers/include/cppoptlib/solver/neldermeadsolver.h"    

template<typename Ta>
class AB : public cppoptlib::Problem<Ta> {
  public:
    AB(int aa) : a(aa){}      
    using typename cppoptlib::Problem<Ta>::TVector;
    //int a = 250;
    Ta value(const TVector &x) {
        return   (1 - x[0]) * (1 - x[0]) + a * (x[1] - x[0] * x[0]) * (x[1] - x[0] * x[0]);
}    
};   

void test(){

 typedef AB<double> TAB;
    TAB f(250);
    // choose a starting point
    Eigen::VectorXd x(2); x << -1, 2;   

    // choose a solver
    cppoptlib::NelderMeadSolver<TAB> solver;
    // and minimize the function
    solver.minimize(f, x);
    // print argmin
    std::cout << "argmin      " << x.transpose() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f in argmin " << f(x) << std::endl;    
}    

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    test();       

    return 0;
}
```

Andwhen i compile i received this :

```
essai.cpp: In constructor ‘AB<Ta>::AB(int)’:
essai.cpp:10:18: error: class ‘AB<Ta>’ does not have any field named ‘a’
     AB(int aa) : a(aa){}   
                  ^
essai.cpp: In member function ‘Ta AB<Ta>::value(const typename cppoptlib::Problem<Ta>::TVector&)’:
essai.cpp:14:44: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
         return   (1 - x[0]) * (1 - x[0]) + a * (x[1] - x[0] * x[0]) * (x[1] - x[0] * x[0]);
                                            ^
```

If you have some ideas it will help me a lot because right now i have no ideas how to do this !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: So give `AB` a constructor that takes `int` parameter, and initialize `a` from this parameter. This is C++ 101.

Comment: Thanks for your answer have you got an example ? Because i never do a constructor of a class in main only with *.cpp and *.hpp files. Thank you a lot !

Comment: Just add this line to `class AB` after `public`: `AB(int aa) : a(aa) {}`. Then in `test`, declare `f` like this: `TAB f(250);` It's no different whether you define the class in a header file or in a source file.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work :/ it told me that :essai.cpp: In constructor ‘AB<Ta>::AB(int)’:
essai.cpp:10:20: error: class ‘AB<Ta>’ does not have any field named ‘a’
      AB (int aa) : a(aa){}
                    ^
essai.cpp: In member function ‘Ta AB<Ta>::value(const typename cppoptlib::Problem<Ta>::TVector&)’:
essai.cpp:14:44: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
         return   (1 - x[0]) * (1 - x[0]) + a * (x[1] - x[0] * x[0]) * (x[1] - x
                                            ^

Comment: In the code you show, class `AB` does too have a member named `a`. The code you actually compile must therefore be different from the code you show. I can't help you with code I can't see.

Comment: Why did you comment out the line that solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to create a constructor to input a given value to object of AB in function test

```
  template<typename Ta>
  class AB : public cppoptlib::Problem<Ta> 
  {
    int a;
   public:
    using typename cppoptlib::Problem<Ta>::TVector;
    AB(int num):a(num)
    {}
    Ta value(const TVector &x)
    {
      return   (1 - x[0]) * (1 - x[0]) + a * (x[1] - x[0] * x[0]) * (x[1] - x[0] * x[0]); 
    }
  };


  void test()
  {

    typedef AB<double> TAB;
    TAB f(25); //initializes a with 25
```